# C++ algorithm for finding files

Tags: c++, windows, console-application

I have to write console C++ program which finds specific file under C:.
File name with its extension should be written in standard input, and the program should show its location (first one, I'm not interested in others if there is more than one).
Does anyone knows the algorithm or some library which I could use for this?
If affirmative, please post the answer here.

Thanks in my name, and in name of anyone else who might find this useful.

Comment: There are many file-finding programs already. Is this homework?

Comment: Yap. I actually do not need already done program, I'm more interested in explanation. :)

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/tutorial.html

Comment: You can  use boost, or you can use Windows native functions FindFirstFile and FindNextFile.

Comment: Are you primarily interested in a conceptual algorithm or really in c++-source code?

Comment: I'll try the FindFirstFile...
@phimuemue
I have to write the program, so I'm interested in both right now, but conceptual algorithm is necessary in order to understand how it works.

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm for this is straightforward: After you've read the file name, you start at the root directory, get all file names and compare them to your name. If none matches, you recursively repeat this algorithm for each subdirectory until you find the file.

Comment: This is the easiest approach, but performance will be poor compared to e.g. NTFS master file table enumeration.

Comment: @BenVoigt: But NTFS master file table enumeration will help you nothing if the file system happens not to be NTFS. Also, this is a homework, and I can't imagine they want an NTFS-specific solution.

Comment: The question is tagged `windows` and asks about enumerating `C:`.  It's been a while since any version of Windows could install to a non-NTFS filesystem.

Comment: Can't XP be installed on FAT32? After all, XP is still in widespread use.